# How to resolve GLIBC 2.14 error from RHEL6 servers

Tags: java

I have recently installed openjdk8 on RHEL6 and 7 servers. Build works on  RHEl7 but giving error on RHEL6:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ../bin/../lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so)
```

ldd (GNU libc) 2.12 is installed on RHEL6, Do i need to upgrade it ?

How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Java binary that you installed was compiled against different version of GLIBC. You might be using an RPM for RHEL7 on RHEL6.

You either need to compile the Java on RHEL6 yourself or find the correct RPM. As per [OpenJDK Life Cycle and Support Policy docs](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1299013#OpenJDK_Life_Cycle) Java 8 is only officially supported on RHEL 6.6 or higher.